# pdfjs throws a TypeError, losing hair

Tags: node.js, pdf, typeerror, pdf.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist";
import pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

class PdfLoader extends Component {
  state = {
    pdfDocument: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { url } = this.props;

    pdfjs
      .getDocument({ url: url, eventBusDispatchToDOM: true })
      .promise.then(pdfDocument => {
        this.setState({
          pdfDocument: pdfDocument
        });
      });
  }
}
```

This builds fine under yarn, but at run time, pdfjs.getDocument (ok, minimized, something like co.a.getDocument) throws a TypeError saying it can't handle getDocument of undefined.  My other source files and the console show that I am loading my pdf.worker..worker.js file.

I inherited this code from a former co-worker and a previous build on his machine worked, but on mine it always throws this error.

Comment: Just making sure - pdfjs-dist is installed in your node_modules folder? Either in the project or globally? It seems like the import resolves undefined, indicating either the package can't be found or node has trouble importing it.

Comment: Yes.  And as a 'brain death' check, I changed the pdfjs-dists name to something it shouldn't find and the build process threw an error.  So the build process is finding it, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok this might also be futile but I'll just go to my next logical step in debugging. Might there be a version disparity between the version you have installed and your coworker? The export signature of the package might have changed. My naive attempt would be to see if `import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist'` works. If not, I'd either look at any possible building differences betwen you and your coworkers project. Because React does seem to import properly, so it's not like node is not cooperating. Maybe look into the source code of pdfjs-dist and see how it exports its functions.

Comment: That threw a completely different set of errors.  And the pdf.worker file is loading because chrome is complaining about it's associated map file not loading (completely different thing with what I have to do to get code to the server).

Comment: Tried that and it threw different errors.  Then another co-worker pointed out the 'new' proper way to include it is const pdfjs = require("pdfjs-dist");  Note: It threw the same errors your suggestion did, so apparently either would work.

Now tracking down other errors which appear to be various package versioning issues.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't of much help at all. Good luck! I know how annoying these kind of problems can be :(